# Connect to neo4j using jersey from android using REST API

Tags: android, rest, nullpointerexception, neo4j, jersey

I have a neo4j server running on my laptop on the port 7474. It is enabled to listen on localhost:7474/ , 0.0.0.0:7474/ and :7474/. I am referring to the official documentation on the Community Documentation Page -  http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-java-rest-client-example.html.

I am trying to connect to the database and create a node through an android app.

I have added the jersey-bundle-1.8.jar in my app's libs folder. I am able to use all the functions defined in the library. No errors are reported for calling the functions.
Using the documentation,  i am able to connect to the neo4j server running on my laptop as shown in the picture.

ISSUE FACED :

So moving ahead, i clicked the button to create a node, again picking the code from the reference page mentioned above.

What happened was that the app crashed and raised exceptions (as shown in the picture). The exceptions raised are attached in log

`03-28 17:50:05.691: I/SurfaceTextureClient(10165): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5cc8a588) fps:0.09, dur:10766.62, max:10766.62, min:10766.62
03-28 17:50:05.691: I/SurfaceTextureClient(10165): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5cc8a588, api:1, last queue time elapsed:10766.62
03-28 17:50:05.709: D/dalvikvm(10165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 272K, 16% free 5656K/6664K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 27ms
03-28 17:50:05.747: V/Provider/Settings(10165): invalidate [system]: current 208 != cached 0
03-28 17:50:05.750: V/Provider/Settings(10165): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): create new thread
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): new thread created
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): update thread list
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x5e2ef000
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=12: created from interp
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): start new thread
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=12: notify debugger
03-28 17:50:05.751: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=12 (AsyncTask #1): calling run()
03-28 17:50:05.768: I/dalvikvm(10165): Failed resolving Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry; interface 2320 'Lorg/osgi/framework/SynchronousBundleListener;'
03-28 17:50:05.768: W/dalvikvm(10165): Link of class 'Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;' failed
03-28 17:50:05.768: I/dalvikvm(10165): Could not find method com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.OsgiRegistry.getInstance, referenced from method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getOsgiRegistryInstance
03-28 17:50:05.768: W/dalvikvm(10165): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7747: Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;.getInstance ()Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;
03-28 17:50:05.768: D/dalvikvm(10165): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0008
03-28 17:50:05.769: I/dalvikvm(10165): Failed resolving Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry; interface 2320 'Lorg/osgi/framework/SynchronousBundleListener;'
03-28 17:50:05.769: W/dalvikvm(10165): Link of class 'Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;' failed
03-28 17:50:05.770: W/dalvikvm(10165): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;)
03-28 17:50:05.835: D/dalvikvm(10165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 359K, 17% free 5690K/6784K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 20ms
03-28 17:50:05.862: D/dalvikvm(10165): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
03-28 17:50:05.862: D/dalvikvm(10165): create new thread
03-28 17:50:05.862: D/dalvikvm(10165): new thread created
03-28 17:50:05.862: D/dalvikvm(10165): update thread list
03-28 17:50:05.862: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x5e2fb000
03-28 17:50:05.862: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=13: created from interp
03-28 17:50:05.863: D/dalvikvm(10165): start new thread
03-28 17:50:05.863: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=12: exiting
03-28 17:50:05.863: W/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41dba9a8)
03-28 17:50:05.863: W/System.err(10165): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
03-28 17:50:05.864: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=13: notify debugger
03-28 17:50:05.864: W/System.err(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
03-28 17:50:05.864: D/dalvikvm(10165): threadid=13 (AsyncTask #2): calling run()
03-28 17:50:05.865: W/System.err(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:160)
03-28 17:50:05.865: W/System.err(10165):    at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
03-28 17:50:05.865: W/System.err(10165):    at com.example.neo4j.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
03-28 17:50:05.865: W/System.err(10165):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
03-28 17:50:05.865: W/System.err(10165):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17431)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 17:50:05.866: W/System.err(10165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-28 17:50:05.867: W/System.err(10165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-28 17:50:05.867: W/System.err(10165):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
03-28 17:50:05.867: W/System.err(10165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 17:50:05.867: W/System.err(10165): Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
03-28 17:50:05.868: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
03-28 17:50:05.868: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
03-28 17:50:05.868: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
03-28 17:50:05.869: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
03-28 17:50:05.869: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:560)
03-28 17:50:05.869: W/System.err(10165):    at com.example.neo4j.RESTCreateNode.doInBackground(RESTCreateNode.java:33)
03-28 17:50:05.869: W/System.err(10165):    at com.example.neo4j.RESTCreateNode.doInBackground(RESTCreateNode.java:1)
03-28 17:50:05.869: W/System.err(10165):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-28 17:50:05.869: W/System.err(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-28 17:50:05.870: W/System.err(10165):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-28 17:50:05.870: W/System.err(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-28 17:50:05.870: W/System.err(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-28 17:50:05.870: W/System.err(10165):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
03-28 17:50:05.870: W/System.err(10165): Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
03-28 17:50:05.871: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
03-28 17:50:05.871: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
03-28 17:50:05.871: W/System.err(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
03-28 17:50:05.871: W/System.err(10165):    ... 12 more
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165): Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:560)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.example.neo4j.RESTCreateNode.doInBackground(RESTCreateNode.java:33)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.example.neo4j.RESTCreateNode.doInBackground(RESTCreateNode.java:1)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    ... 4 more
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165): Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
03-28 17:50:05.879: E/AndroidRuntime(10165):    ... 12 more
03-28 17:50:06.425: D/OpenGLRenderer(10165): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-28 17:50:06.654: D/OpenGLRenderer(10165): Flushing caches (mode 1)
03-28 17:50:06.666: D/OpenGLRenderer(10165): Flushing caches (mode 0)`

I started googling the issue and found a solution proposed  by user Lucas Ventura
 here - http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/java-lang-NullPointerException-on-Android-td4212447.html
I implemented the solution and it started giving me exception -

"NullPointerException at MediaType.java:119".

I tried googling further but it didn't yeild anything useful.

A little insight on this topic would help me a lot. 
Please let me know if i am following something in a wrong manner. If not, is there any other approach that I can use to connect to neo4j server in a RESTful way.
Also let me know if this is the answer i am looking for -https://github.com/giorgio-zamparelli/jersey-android

[image: a image-1]

[image: a image-2]